# Residual Plot and QQ Plot

Tags: data-visualization, residuals, qq-plot

Is this a good [residuals plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwxnO.png) and  [QQ plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3nkW.png)  to verify the constant variance and normality assumption?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that both of those show significant evidence for violation of the assumptions of normality and homoskedasticity. The residuals at one fitted value have far greater variance than at the other. Meanwhile, the QQ plot suggests much heavier tails than expected.